# If I find an alement in a vector pairs using std:find, how can I get the values from the vector into a string?

Tags: c++, vector, find, std-pair

After using the find function to check if `string check;` is in a `vector<pair<string, string>>` by checking the `pair[i].first`, i would like to get the elements in `pair[i].second` into a separate string `string holder;`

how would I do this without using loops or is it inevitable and that's the only way? Can the find function return the value in addition to the true or false?

Comment: "i would like to get the elements in pair[i].second into a separate string " - then just copy it into one. What's the problem?

Comment: the find function returns an iterator, the iterator points to the value `it->second`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl i would if i could. but i am not using a loop to find if the value is present. so cant just do `holder = pair[i].second` because I am using an iterator of the vector to check if `string check` is present, and by doing so it only returns true or false. Can't put the element into it. Remember it is a `vector<pair<string, string>>` i would have to cycle through the vector with a loop and I am trying to avoid that

Comment: @john I shall try that, thankyou

Comment: @john so would I be able to do `it.second -> holder` or is there a proper way of doing it?

Comment: No, `holder = it->second;` (assuming your iterator variable is called `it`).

Comment: @john oh ok got it, thankyou very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dereference the iterator returned by the [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) function. The underlying value the iterator points to is of type [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair). To access the pair's underlying member objects called `first` and `second` via an iterator use `->first` and `->second` respectively:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> v { {"aa", "bb"}, { "cc", "dd" }};
auto mypair = std::make_pair<std::string, std::string>("cc", "dd");
auto foundit = std::find(std::begin(v), std::end(v), mypair);
std::string s1;
std::string s2;
if (foundit != std::end(v)) {
    s1 = foundit->first; // first element
    s2 = foundit->second; // second element
}
else {
    std::cout << "v does not contain the pair." << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

std::find returns an iterator to the found item or end() if it is not found.  So you have an iterator to your pair if it's found.

Comment: so just do as john mentioned in the comment and do: `it -> second` ?